# SDL with external context

Tags: c#, sdl, ati

Can SDL use an external graphics context (context that created by another graphics library)? and how?
(Maybe something like the OpenTK call 'CreateDummyContext')

I'm using c#/VS2010/ATI Radeon HD 3470

Comment: If you created the context with another library then you don't need SDL to do anything with the context. You'll only be using OpenGL calls to "do" stuff. You can still use SDL, but not for events and window manager.

Comment: Thanks for replay,
Actually I'm using 'Tao Framework', so if I used Tao.OpenGl, how to inform it about the external context?

Comment: I can't find much info on the Tao framework, but the sourcefourge wiki page says it's superseded by OpenTK (yet it's still updated this year somewhere). Perhaps you can look at this: https://github.com/sulix/opentk-sdl2 it's the OpenTK with SDL2 as backend.